# c++17 (c++20) unordered map and custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have some issues with map/unordered_map and custom allocator
my allocator looks like this, according to documentation of visual studio.
I derived my allocator from base type to ensure all template types like allocator::value_type is set correctly.

```
template <class T>
class std_allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
   public:
    std_allocator() noexcept;
    std_allocator(const std_allocator& aOther) noexcept;
    template <class O>
    std_allocator(const std_allocator<O>& aOther) noexcept;

   public:
    void deallocate(T* const aPtr, const size_t aCount);
    T* allocate(const size_t aCount);
};
```

now i defined a my unordered map:

```
class Test {
   private:
    std::unordered_map<const SomeObject*,
                       void*,
                       std::hash<const SomeObject*>,
                       std::equal_to<const SomeObject*>,
                       std_allocator<std::pair<const SomeObject*, void*>>>
        mData;
};
```

no i got the following compiler error:
:\Development\Microsoft\Visual Studio 2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\list(784,49): error C2338: list<T, Allocator> requires that Allocator's value_type match T (See N4659 26.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/16 allocator_type) Either fix the allocator value_type or define _ENFORCE_MATCHING_ALLOCATORS=0 to suppress this diagnostic.

from the unodered_map header the template looks like this

```
template <class _Kty, class _Ty, class _Hasher = hash<_Kty>, class _Keyeq = equal_to<_Kty>,
    class _Alloc = allocator<pair<const _Kty, _Ty>>>
```

from my point of view it looks correct. I also tried using a key without "const" except for the pair definition in allocator. the error says that I may disable the error by defining a constant but I guess that would be not a good idea. can some give some advice here?

Cheers

Comment: I am not sure that you have defined all the needed member  functions, I seem to remember there need to be a lot more.

Comment: According to the c++17 documentation you just need allocate and deallocate plus several c'tors. All other functions are marked as deprecared and will be removed in c++20. I use the same allocator in vectors and it works without issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key detail:

```
class _Alloc = allocator<pair<const _Kty, _Ty>>>
```

The `const` part is the key. The key itself must be constant, which is not the same as a pointer to a constant object. There's a difference between a pointer to a constant object, and constant pointer to a (possibly const) object.

Your map definitely appears to be keyed by a pointer to a constant object. gcc 10 compiles this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

template <class T>
class std_allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
   public:
    std_allocator() noexcept;
    std_allocator(const std_allocator& aOther) noexcept;
    template <class O>
    std_allocator(const std_allocator<O>& aOther) noexcept;

   public:
    void deallocate(T* const aPtr, const size_t aCount);
    T* allocate(const size_t aCount);
};

class SomeObject {};

class Test {
   private:
    std::unordered_map<const SomeObject*,
                       void*,
                       std::hash<const SomeObject*>,
                       std::equal_to<const SomeObject*>,
                       std_allocator<std::pair<const SomeObject* const, void*>>>
        mData;
};
```

Comment: yes I see the const is key here. putting an additonal const to make the object const and not the pointer works. thanks